# blueimp-jQuery-File-Upload to defined directory

Tags: jquery, file-upload, blueimp

I'm using blueimp fileupload to upload images associated with individual property records. The images for each property are stored in  subdirectory of files identified by the record id - for example files/1/img.jpg.

To upload the images to a specified subdirectory I added a hidden field to the form

```
<input type="hidden" name="property_id" id="property_id" value="<?php echo($pid);?>">
```

In main.js I added the following code

```
// Set additional form data just before the upload starts
    $('#fileupload').bind('fileuploadsubmit', function (e, data) {
    var id = $('#property_id').val();
    data.formData = {property_id: id};
});
```

I modified index.php as follows (thanks to Nicholas Connor on Google Groups)

```
require('UploadHandler.php');

class CustomUploadHandler extends UploadHandler {

protected function get_user_id() {

   $property_id = @htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['property_id']);

    if (empty($property_id)) {
        @session_start();
        return session_id();
    }

    elseif(isset($property_id)) {
     return $property_id;
    }

 else {
        @session_start();
        return session_id();
        }
    }
}

$upload_handler = new CustomUploadHandler(array(
    'user_dirs' => true
));
```

Everything is working fine, blueimp will create the directory and /thumbs directory if it's not there and upload the images to the correct place. Problem is when I refresh the page (or access the page for the first time) the images are no longer displayed (although they all exist). I'm guessing this is something to do with binding the additional data on the callback for the submit event? Although Firebug is giving me the following on page refresh 
GET http://localhost/property/uploads/?property_id=18

I've been looking for a solution for (seems like) days - so any help much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

I have worked out a solution but seems a bit of a 'hack' so hopefully someone may be able to improve on it.. it does however work so maybe of some help.

Take out the jQuery code block added to main.js (// set additional form data etc) as this was only posting across a value on uploading a file. Then added the property id to the url:

```
$(function () {
    'use strict';

    // get a value for the property id
    var property_id = $('#property_id').val();

    // Initialize the jQuery File Upload widget:
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({

        // Uncomment the following to send cross-domain cookies:
        //xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
        // url modified to include the property_id value
        url: 'uploads/index.php?property_id='+property_id
    });
```

blueimp jQuery-File-Upload will now create a sub-directory of files/ as the property_id, upload the images to the correct directory and display the images when the page is loaded.